# visual studio 2017 srand() crashes (online compiler works)

Tags: c, visual-studio, random, visual-studio-2017, srand

I tried these 3 types of code.

1:  Visual Studio 2017 Output: application crashed.

```
 time_t = t;
 srand((unsigned)time(&t));
```

2: Visual Studio 2017 Output: application crashed.

```
srand (time(NULL));
```

3: Visual Studio 2017 Output: normal print followed by a crash.

```
long t;
time(&t);
srand((unsigned)t);
```

The third variant output/error and build warning prints:
Debug Error!
Run-TimeCheck Failure #2 -Stack around the variable 't' was corrupted

warning C4333: 'function': incompatible types - from 'long *' to 'time_t *const' 
(tried to fix using time_t but the application just crash)

All examples works on online compiler!! [onlinegdb.com](https://www.onlinegdb.com/).
All the test were done with that code below.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define CON 10

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>



float maxB(float v[], int n);

float maxB(float v[], int n) {
    float est;

    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        printf("[%d]: %.2f\n", i, v[i]);
        if (v[i] >= v[i + 1]) {
            est = v[i];
        }
        else
        {
            est = v[i + 1];
        }
    }
    return est;
}

main() {

    srand(time(NULL));

    float v[CON];
    int a;
    printf("how many vector positions to test?\n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    while (a < 0 || a > CON ){
        printf("invalid input!how many vector positions to test?\n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < CON; i++){
        v[i] = (float)(rand() % 10);
    }
    printf("Biggest number %f", maxB(v, a));
}
```

So... what should i do to use random function with visual studio? Should i use another version?

Comment: Your code does not crash for me, and I wouldn't expect it to since I and many others use this exact same method to seed the random number generator all the time. It also doesn't compile for me until I change your `main` function to `int main`. My warnings are also not the same, and in the code you posted `srand` isn't called on line 35. Are you use what you've put in the question is the exact code you're using in Visual Studio? Where you've shown a crash you've also shown output which doesn't happen until long after `srand` is called. I suggest you click retry and see where the crash really is

Comment: On Windows, `long` is only 32-bits, even in WIn64.  However, there's a good chance that `time_t` is 64-bits.  That would account for the 'corruption around `t`' error message for option 3.  The first variant shouldn't compile (the `=` is a syntax error).  Did you actually include `<stdlib.h>` and `<time.h>` when compiling?  If not, that could account for the trouble.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i did try to use time_t, the problem isnt the compile error, it fix as said, but the console closes as soon i input anything.

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` should be good.

Comment: If you'd just not have used screen shots this would be a good question. I cannot read the screen shots. Please post text as text.

Comment: @alk the image has the normal output + debug error saying this : Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 't' was corrupted. Bear in mind that i used the third type in that case, if i change long to time_t it just crash as the other ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the problem was the computer i was using, when i did the test with another machine, it worked!.